# .NET core cannot find XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to recreate the code in .NET Core and i am getting an errors and highlights which do not help to solve a problem.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string content = File.ReadAllText("input.xml");
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.LoadXml(content.Trim());
         XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml");
         doc.Save(writer);
    }

}
```

I tried adding Referece "System.Xml" to dependencies but it generates new errors.

[Errors in .NET Core which do not happen to be in .NET 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjn9G.png)

Edit:

I just wanted to say this code works now.

.NET Core got updated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In your code you basically just copy a file and save it with a new name.

Comment: I am using function called "Trim()" which removes spaces in XML file and makes a wall of text out of xml formatting.

Comment: You are using String Trim which does nothing special for XML strings?

Comment: It does.. Try it on xml file.

Comment: Posting the errors might help others find the issue.

Comment: So the problem is: how to use XmlDocument in .Net Core. You should have documented what you tried in the area of packages etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works now.

In .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the right package from NuGet: `System.Xml.XmlDocument`

And then run `dotnet restore` from a command line (I really don't know if/how you can do this from VS).

After that there is the XmlWriter issue answered by Chien Dang.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 if you right click Dependencies in the Solution Explorer, select Manage Nuget Packages. Click the Browse tab, enter System.Xml.XmlDocument then Install. Visual Studio will download the package and restore it for you.

Comment: Yes, the answer was for VS2015. It's gotten better (less command line) in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create new XmlWriter from a string.
Just remove like the code below:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("input.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(content.Trim());

//XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml");
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

I'm using System.Xml version 4.0.0.0 from .Net Framework 4.5 and it ran ok.
Hope that helps!